# Hibernate: @PreRemove executed, but records didn't delete

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

There is a binding entity of many-to-many relation. When I delete dependent entities, I expect this entity to be deleted too. The preRemove method is called, but hibernate does not build a deletion request.

What am I doing wrong?

Please help, been 3 days trying to solve the problem((

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "SOME_TABLE_NAME")
@IdClass(ExpertAndRequestId.class)
public class ExpertAndRequest implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long managerId;

    @Id
    private Long requestId;

    private String comment;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "managerId", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    //@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Manager manager;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "requestId", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ParticipantRequest request;

    @PreRemove
    public void preRemove(){
        // THIS METHOD EXECUTED
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you inside a transaction? If not, that might be the problem. Put a breakpoint inside the application and execute the line on your IDE to see what happens (Display view on Eclipse/Evaluating Expressions on IntelliJ). There is a chance it is throwing an exception that is going silent on your code.

Comment: @DanielPereira nothing happens... this.ExpertAndRequestRepository.delete(request) does not return anything, but **preRemove** executed.